# Markerfacecolor ignoring saturation value (python, matplotlib)

Tags: python, colors, plot, matplotlib

The matplotlib spec says:

> In addition, you can specify colors in many weird and wonderful ways, including full names ('green'), hex strings ('#008000'), RGB or RGBA tuples ((0,1,0,1))

...

> markerfacecolor or mfc [can be] any matplotlib color

When I make a simple plot, however, the errorbar is desaturated to 0.1, but not the marker. Can the markerface not take the 4tuple RGBA color?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.errorbar(1,1,1,markerfacecolor=[1,0,0,0.1], color=[1,0,0,0.1], marker='o')
plt.savefig('/test.png')
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work if you use `markerdegecolor` instead of `markerfacecolor`

```
plt.errorbar(1,1,1,markeredgecolor=[0,1,0,0.1], color=[1,0,0,0.1], marker='o')
```

This seems like a bug in `matplotlib` to me.

[issue 1504](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1504), which has now been fixed.

Comment: Hmmm... That does seem to work, so I will use it, but I would expect the edge color to be the border around the circle and the face color to be the fill color.. Thanks!